# appengine + nodejs (or else) // environments variables outside app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

The interface is pretty large, so is the doc and so far could not spot this feature clearly

Is there a place where you set environments variable "à-la-heroku" ? Or setting env vars is not available via the gcloud's console interface ?

I'm getting into gcloud running a ruby web app, the goal is, as you would on a regular server, to be able to reach those env variables with `ENV["VAR_NAME"]`.

I'm not sure which one of appengine or cloud compute services are concerned. As I'd like to keep the setup "handled by google", I'd also like to know how to set those envs without ssh'ing into the machine

I tried by adding those in the Metadata area of the compute engine, but this is obviously not the right way to have it available

Comment: You should be a bit more specific; the Cloud Platform includes several completely different services. Which one specifically?

Comment: right! thanks for your comment. Hope I've added the right specifications

Comment: @Ben have you ever find how to do this? I'm facing the same issue right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set environment variables in app.yaml before you deploy. The documentation for how to do so is [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables).

That documentation is actually for Python, but should apply equally to managed VMs.

Comment: That still doesn't answer to the question, how I can pass those variables from my CI/CD Pipeline without committing that file to git. Only if I create that file with some separate script during deploy, which feels really like a hack for modern days... (I mean - Google Cloud doesn't answer)